# Java Servlet Blank Page After Button Submit

Tags: java, servlets

I've come to a brain lock with this basically, after the user clicks Submit it goes to a blank page it doesn't even get to the servlet. I put a `System.out.println` to test if it reaches the servlet but it doesn't.
Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet03</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.Week01_03</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet03</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/week01_03servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is the servlet

```
package servlets;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Week01_03 extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String userString = request.getParameter("userString");
        out.close();

        char[] vowel = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
        int[] count = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++)
        {
            switch (userString.charAt(i))
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                    count[0]++;
                    break;
                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                    count[1]++;
                    break;
                case 'i':
                case 'I':
                    count[2]++;
                    break;
                case 'o':
                case 'O':
                    count[3]++;
                    break;
                case 'u':
                case 'U':
                    count[4]++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Week01_03</title>");
            out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"Week01_02.css\">");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet Week 01, Exercise 03</h1>");
            out.println("<p class=\"inline\">You typed: '<pre class=\"inline\">" +
                        userString + "</pre>'</p>");
            out.println("<h3>Vowel usage:</h3>");
            out.println("<table>");
            for (int i = 0; i < vowel.length; i++)
            {
                out.println("<tr" + (i%2==0 ? " class=\"shaded\"" : "") + ">" +
                            "<td>'" + vowel[i] +
                            "'</td><td>" + count[i] +
                            "</td></tr>");
            }

            out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
        finally
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /** 
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     */
    public String getServletInfo()
    {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Week 01, Exercise 03</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Week01_03.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Week 01, Exercise 03</h1>
        <form action="week01_03servlet" method="post">
            <p>Type some text in the box:
            <input type="text" name="userString"></p>

            <p>and then click the button, 
                and I'll tell you the frequency of vowel usage:
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the point of `out.close();` ?

Comment: what link did you use to the html page with the form? Did you try a direct link to your servlet?

Comment: Well I thought i did link to the servlet with form 'action="week01_03servlet"'

Comment: You have a try with no catch...you need to catch the error and print to a log or something so you'll know what's going on....in fact, does a try with no catch even actually compile?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this servlet does not works is because of the `out.close()` instruction that is at the begining of the `processRequest()` method.

```
System.out.println("Hello");
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String userString = request.getParameter("userString");
**out.close();**
```

it prematurely closes the PrintWriter that is used to send a response to the client. So the client get only a reponse with a HTTP `header content-type: "text/html;charset=UTF-8"` but with a empty body.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Philippe G, the issue is likely the premature out.close()

You've printed a message to the console prior to that but may not ever see it. The output may not be gong where you expect due to logging configuration, and also System.out may be buffered and not be written out till some time later.

You should generally switch this kind of system.out.println to use System.err.println instead, and make sure the output is not going off somewhere to either a log file, or being discarded completely by the container

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect in the end of the doPost.

```
response.sendRedirect("/yourpage");
```